# Union inside json_agg with json_build_object

Tags: json, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id integer, value text);

INSERT INTO test1
    VALUES (1, 'xyz'), (2, 'xxy');

CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id integer, value text);

INSERT INTO test2
    VALUES (3, 'yyy'), (4, 'yxy');
```

---

How in some elegant way, union data from another table? Here's just simple example, but there might be some joins, possibly same column names from different tables etc.

```
SELECT json_agg (json_build_object(
        'ID', t1.id, 
        'someText', t1.value )) AS jbo
FROM test1 t1
```

Something like this gives syntax error:

```
SELECT
json_agg(
    SELECT
        json_build_object('ID', t1.id, 'someText', t1.value)
    FROM test1 t1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    json_build_object('ID', t2.id, 'someText', t2.value)
    FROM test2 t2
    ) AS jbo
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=09e3e2941b69202c2bb48b5444cc0115)

Comment: What is the desired output? What JOINs are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the subquery with the union in the `json_agg()`, but in the `FROM` statement:

```
SELECT json_agg(jbo.val)
FROM (
    SELECT json_build_object('ID', t1.id, 'someText', t1.value)
    FROM test1 t1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT json_build_object('ID', t2.id, 'someText', t2.value)
    FROM test2 t2
) AS jbo(val)
```

<sub>([updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5ae81abab85445ea69d1e2db9d5355b1))</sub>

Comment: I found it problematic now that in the results there is created outter array named 'json_build_object', how to get rid of it?

Comment: Ok, managed it, selects should be names same as whole subquery, so for example
    SELECT json_build_object('ID', t1.id, 'someText', t1.value) as jbo

Comment: @sh4rkyy Right, we want to aggregate the json objects into an array, not the entire (single-column) row. Fixed.